# How to get JSON from php file using get()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, json

Below is the code from where I am trying to fetch JSON from data.php file. What is the mistake I am making?

I am using XAMPP here to fetch the data. The path is correct. I also tried using an absolute path, but no luck.

Opening the absolute path in the browser fetches the array of data I am trying to echo here.

```html
//Get data, and render chart
$.get("/web1/chart/data.php", function(data){
  //Get data
  var parsedData = ParseData(data);
  //Render chart
  InitChart(parsedData);
});
```

Comment: What is in `data.php`?

Comment: did you try JSON.stringify(data)?

Comment: show us the code of `data.php`?

Comment: What is `ParseData()`?  What is `InitChart()`? What do you get when you do `console.log(data);`

Comment: it's js code. not php code. with php use include_once or require. for api use curl

Comment: What do you mean you use xamp to fetch the data? don't you mean you use SQL? We will need to see the code from `data.php`. Also can you query your file directly (not with javascript) from the address bar?

Comment: data.php is the file which is fetching me the data as JSON .I am able to receive it.Nothing wrong with it.The problem is the JS above,where I am trying to display the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you no where mentioned the data type is JSON, Please try to use $.getJSON( instead of $.get

Otherwise specify the data type as JSON in your get request.

```
$.get("/web1/chart/data.php", function( data ) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}, "json" );
```

Comment: I tried using $.getJSON . it has to be a .JSON file .But here its a .php file.So wont work

Comment: Edited my answer for better clarity. What about trying second answer.